# Accessing data (memory) based on event trigger between two programs

Tags: c++, networking, memory, buffer

This question might be quite fundamental to some people, but it would be great if someone can clear my doubts here. I have two software programs (two processes) and they are communicating through standard TCP connection via network. For example, Program A acts like a server constantly waiting for instruction and data from Program B. Once Program A received the data, it immediately stored the data in a vector array, and execute a function that uses the data in the array and clears it at the end. For example, inside Program A:

```
std::vector<int> m_dataArray;

Run()
{
    m_received = false;
    while(1)
    {
        if(m_received)
        {
            Execution();
        }
    }
}

Listener(int data)
{
    m_dataArray.push_back(data);    
    m_received = true;
}

Execution()
{
    m_received = false;

    // read from the data array and do something

    m_dataArray.clear();
}
```

My question is if Program B kept sending data to Program A, will Program A put all these incoming data into a buffer until Program A finishes its current execution before putting the new set of data into the array? or it will have problem accessing memory at the same time. (e.g. will the m_received flag be flicked all the time even when Program A is still in the Execution stage?)

If this is going to be an issue, what is the best way to implement something like this to avoid any issues? I thought about having Program A issuing a "completed" signal back to Program B before sending the next data.

Comment: in your example are listener, run (the receiver) and execution (worker) concurrent (as in different threads/processes) or not?

Comment: Currently they are not. Will it be better to be on the different threads or not?

Comment: its fine then listener must be called by an interrupt? if so its unknown what the behaviour of run will be but there will be no issue with access of memory at the same time.. you will need to better control how run and execute behave if the contents of datarray or received changes between operations

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of making Run and Execution not have any issues with what Listener might do while they are executing

```
std::vector<int> m_dataArray;

Run()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(m_dataArrayBuffer.length > 0)
        {
            // we take the data out and use it in execute
            // these operations are independent of listener adding additional data
            int data = m_dataArrayBuffer.pop();
            Execution(data);
        }
    }
}

Listener(int data)
{
    m_dataArrayBuffer.push_back(data);    
}

Execution(int data)
{
    // user the data and do something
}
```